# Cannot convert VARCHAR to INT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote variable in sql

Here is code

```
 DECLARE @rowNumber INT
SET @rowNumber = 'SELECT CAST((-1) * ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY (t.Id)) AS INT)
FROM [dbo].[AbpTenants] as t
ORDER BY t.Id'
EXEC (@rowNumber)
```

But when I try to run this, I got this error.

> S0001][245] Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT CAST((-1) * ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY (t.Id)) AS INT) FROM [dbo].[AbpTenants] as t ORDER BY t.Id' to data type int.

Where is problem and how I can convert it to int?

Comment: Your are setting an integer to a string.  That doesn't make sense.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: Okay, how I can fix this?@GordonLinoff

Comment: I want to get row number of all rows in table in minus. And wrote this in variable@GordonLinoff

Comment: I need int, not VARCHAR @SalmanA

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not make sense for multiple reasons:

- You are setting an integer parameter to a string.
- You are setting a single value to the results of a query, that will likely return multiple rows.
- You are casting the result of a function that returns an int to an int.
- You are creating a negative number and calling it "row number".  Row numbers are not usually negative.

I suspect you want a calculation, not a subquery.  If you want the count of rows in the table, you would use:

```
DECLARE @rowNumber INT;

SELECT @rowNumber = COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[AbpTenants] t;
```

This is not quite equivalent to your logic, but it does make sense.

Comment: I want to get row number of all rows in table in minus. And wrote this in variable

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiplication with negative number :

```
DECLARE @rowNumber INT

SET @rowNumber = COUNT(*) * -1
FROM [dbo].[AbpTenants] t;

SELECT @rowNumber
```

**EDIT :** If you want row numbers for all rows then you need table variable instead.

You have a scaler variable `@rowNumber`, and it will hold only single value not multiple values.

```
DECLARE @rownumber TABLE (id INT, rowNumbers INT)

INSERT INTO @rownumber (id, rowNumbers)
    SELECT t.id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.id)
    FROM [dbo].[AbpTenants] t;

SELECT *
FROM @rownumber;
```

Comment: I don't need count I need row number for row in negative

Comment: Okay, but I need to use this rownumber in next query

Comment: So I guess I need scalar variable

Comment: Unfortunately everyone is guessing because no one understands exactly what you are trying to accomplish. So post a short script with a 2 row table that demonstrates what output you want to generate and the logic to use to generate that output. What you posted produces a resultset containing many rows even if the rows have a single column.